# problem with error handling when I use readlink

Tags: tcl

I'm having an issue when I run following command.

I tried both way but didn't get desired output.

`if{[catch {file readlink $ver}]}` then it gives output as "if{1} unknown command".

`if{[catch [file readlink $ver]]}` then it gives error, it does not catch error.

I want it to catch error & run body part of `if` block.

Comment: If you're getting the error `if{1} unknown command` that means you did not put a space between `if` and `{[catch ...`

Comment: Thanks... That was silly one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax for the `catch` block:

```
if { [catch {file readlink $ver} errmsg] }  { 

puts $errmsg # will print the actual error

} else { 
continue the body part!!!
}
```